# How do I apply "ngModel #something="ngModel"" to a dynamic form element in a template driven form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm getting an error when submitting my form saying it's not defined.  I started researching and discovered I needed to add `ngModel #something="ngModel` to each of my inputs in order for the form to pick up on the inputs like in the example below from this website https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven

```
<input
  type="email"
  placeholder="Your email address"
  name="email"

  ngModel
  #userEmail="ngModel"

  required>
```

Pretty straitforward and simple, except in my case I made a `question-shell`component that handles all my different types of questions by triggering an `ngIf` condition in the template according to a `template` field in my data, so my text input looks like this.

```
<!-- SMALL TEXT INPUT -->
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'sm_input'">

    <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

        <label class="form-group center-block">
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" [attr.value]="Data.question">
            {{Data.question}}:
            <input class="form-control"
                [attr.id]="Data.id"
                [attr.name]="Data.name"
                [(ngModel)]="UserResponse.answer"
            >
        </label>

    </fieldset>

</ng-container>
```

Due to the nature of my component I can't just add

```
ngModel
#email="ngModel"
```

to my inputs as a whole because it will be used for names, phone numbers, websites etc.  Besides that if I have a bunch of elements with the same name in the form I'm guessing they'll all just redefine the same property on the form as a whole giving me incomplete results.

So far the way the form is set up goes like this

`questionnaire template`

```
<form #branding="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(branding)" class="col-xs-12">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let a of Data?.sections">
        <question-shell *ngFor="let b of a.questions" [Data]="b"></question-shell>
    </ng-container>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

then the `question-shell` has different chunks of html like the example I gave above that the data binds to. Is there a way I can store a value in my data that I can use to create this dynamically somehow?  Here's a plunker, please excuse the bootstrap not working.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I read, if you use ngModel by itself (no =), it will automatically add a property using the name specified by the name attribute.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: I just added a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Following way i have used to bind name and disabled attribute to my dynamic template, in your case this may vary for ngModel but giving this for reference

```
// question-shell.component.ts
export class question-shell implements OnInit {
  @Input() nmgModel: any;
}
// question-shell.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'sm_input'">

    <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

        <label class="form-group center-block">
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" [attr.value]="Data.question">
            {{Data.question}}:
            <input class="form-control"
                [attr.id]="Data.id"
                [attr.name]="Data.name"
                [(ngModel)]="{{nmgModel}}"
            >
        </label>

    </fieldset>

</ng-container>

// questionnaire template
<form #branding="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(branding)" class="col-xs-12">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let a of Data?.sections">
        <question-shell *ngFor="let b of a.questions" [Data]="b" [ngModel]="value"></question-shell>
    </ng-container>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: can you please explain?  I added a plunker to my post too